# Whenever I drag the Crystal Report Viewer to show the form it goes down without showing from view

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-xi, crystal-reports-server

Whenever I drag the Crystal Report Viewer to show the form it goes down
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yY29.png)

Answer (score 0):

Crystal Report Problem and solution | crystal report viewer can't work in form | report problem fix
https://youtu.be/678hU5UWOR0